# Looking for an infinite series resembling the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm looking for a function $f(x)$ that has the following property:

$\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(kx) = r^k$

for some real $0 < r < 1$, and at least for strictly positive integer $k$.

Does such a function exist?

This could also be thought of in terms of some sequence of real numbers $f[n]$.

Comment: Do you **really**  want  a function $\;f\;$ such that $\;f(k)+f(2k)+f(3k)+\ldots=r^k\;$ ?

Comment: Right. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @Mi No, not really...It is just that it looks pretty weird to me, that's all. It isn't a power series nor a series of functions, but just the sum of the values of $\;f\;$ on integral multiples of some number $\;k\;$ ....and that must equal $\;r^k\;$ ...It'll be interesting if someone can come up with something like that.

Comment: That's true. Would it be clearer if I rewrote this in terms of some sequence f[n] instead of f(x)?

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321432/looking-for-infinite-series-resembling-an-exponential

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\;r^k=e^{k\log r}\;$ , so

$$e^{k\log r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{k^n(\log r)^n}{n!}$$

Yet the above doesn't have the form you seem to be searching...